# Rails 4 - Remove all traces of a previously used Active Record database

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, rubymine-7, schema-migration

This is the Log.

```
ActiveRecord::SchemaMigration Load (5.0ms)  SELECT `schema_migrations`.* FROM `schema_migrations`
Unable to load samplero, underlying cause No such file to load -- samplero 

org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1065:in `require'
C:/jruby-1.7.12/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:228:in `require'
C:/jruby-1.7.12/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:213:in `load_dependency'
C:/jruby-1.7.12/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:228:in `require'
C:/jruby-1.7.12/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:329:in `require_or_load'
C:/jruby-1.7.12/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:288:in `depend_on'
C:/jruby-1.7.12/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:206:in `require_dependency'
C:/jruby-1.7.12/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/fixtures.rb:773:in `try_to_load_dependency'
C:/jruby-1.7.12/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/fixtures.rb:792:in `require_fixture_classes'
org/jruby/RubyArray.java:1613:in `each'
C:/jruby-1.7.12/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/fixtures.rb:790:in `require_fixture_classes'
C:/jruby-1.7.12/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/fixtures.rb:768:in `fixtures'
C:/Files/Ontash/mediconversion/JRUBY_ON_RAILS_CODE/medi_con/test/test_helper.rb:12:in `TestCase'
C:/Files/Ontash/mediconversion/JRUBY_ON_RAILS_CODE/medi_con/test/test_helper.rb:5:in `(root)'
org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1065:in `require'
C:/Files/Ontash/mediconversion/JRUBY_ON_RAILS_CODE/medi_con/app/dao/cdr_parse_match_dao.rb:1:in `(root)'
org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1065:in `require'
C:/Files/Ontash/mediconversion/JRUBY_ON_RAILS_CODE/medi_con/app/dao/cdr_parse_match_dao.rb:2:in `(root)'
file:/C:/jruby-1.7.12/lib/jruby.jar!/jruby/kernel19/kernel.rb:1:in `(root)'
org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1065:in `require'
file:/C:/jruby-1.7.12/lib/jruby.jar!/jruby/kernel19/kernel.rb:21:in `require_relative'
C:/Files/Ontash/mediconversion/JRUBY_ON_RAILS_CODE/medi_con/app/service/cdr_parse_match.rb:1:in `(root)'
org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1081:in `load'
-e:1:in `(root)'
```

I want to know where the SELECT `schema_migrations`.* FROM `schema_migrations` query is being called so that i can remove it hopefully this error will go away then. Previously I've tested out the database connection using Active Record and since the load on memory was so high I decided to work with sequel gem. I want to remove all traces of the previously used Active Record database, I've tried deleting the migration file and schema from the db folder but the error still persists.

Comment: Are the migration file and the schema file the ONLY things you have deleted so far?

Comment: @Beartech I'm not sure about it, there are a couple others working on the same thing. Sorry for the late reply.